# How to get row number then looping through selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating macro, which would create Word document from template and move info from each selected row in Excel. So far, documents are created and information is moved, but from wrong cells:

For example, when I select cells from C5 to C8 macro creates 3 documents and populate them with info from C1 to C3. I need these docs to be populated with info from selected rows.

I understand I need to fix reference, but I cant think a way to refer to selected range row in which loop currently is. Please give me some advice. My code so far:

```
Sub Move_info_UPDT()

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\Users\grusa\Desktop\test2.dotx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    With objDoc
        'I need it to  be cell from the same row loop currently is
        ' now this line move info to first doc from C1, to second from C2 and etc.
        .ContentControls.Item(1).Range.Text = Worksheets("Lapas").Cells(i, "C").Value
    End With

    objWord.Visible = True

    Next

objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Additional question: since whole process can take a while, are there a way to show some kind of loading bar to show that macro is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the loop to *absolute* counting not *relatively* to the selected range as you did.

For a status information you can use `Application.StatusBar` to show the working step of the macro in Excel's status bar.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Move_info_UPDT()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object

    Dim ProcessRange As Range
    Set ProcessRange = Selection

    Dim i As Long
    For i = ProcessRange.Row To ProcessRange.Rows.Count + ProcessRange.Row - 1
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\Users\grusa\Desktop\test2.dotx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

        With objDoc
            'I need it to  be cell from the same row loop currently is
            ' now this line move info to first doc from C1, to second from C2 and etc.
            .ContentControls.Item(1).Range.Text = ProcessRange.Parent.Cells(i, "C").Value
        End With

        objWord.Visible = True
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i - ProcessRange.Row + 1 & " of " & ProcessRange.Rows.Count
        DoEvents 'keep Excel responsive
    Next i

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, works almost perfectly. Just one question, is it possible to make this code indifferent to selected column? Because for some reason if I choose any other column than A, info from wrong cells is moved: if selected range A5:A6 then value from C5:C6 is moved, but if selected range is B5:B6, then value from D5:D6 is moved, despite formula explicitly saying `.Cells(i, "C").Value`

Comment: @Gexas See my edit. In this case it is better to use an absolute row counting and reference.

Comment: Thanks again, tested and now values moves as intended. Last question, now status bar writes process numbers out of range, like 13 of 2. My guess it is because I added more procedures to `With objDoc` How can I change it to show only Word documents generated count? For eg. I select 3 row to generate 3 Word doc, so progress bar show Progress: 2 of 3 (like it worked before edit)

Comment: @Gexas Sorry forgot to adjust the StatusBar counting. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these for the start and end of your loop:

```
Dim FirstRow as Long
Dim LastRow as Long
FirstRow = Selection.Rows(1).Row
LastRow = FirstRow + Selection.Rows.Count
```

The loop then goes like:

```
For i = FirstRow To LastRow
    ' ...
Next i
```